# After you input a string that contains a single * character, how can I replace that character with the second string I create in my code?

Tags: string, replace, wildcard

I'm taking AP Computer Science in my high school and this week's assignment was to create a program that will work like:

```
>>Enter the first String:
<<D*g
>>Enter the replacement String:
<<in
>>Ding
```

However, our teacher hasn't really taught us anything helpful and almost every single person in my class is confused except for the Teacher Aid and teacher himself.

Could anybody help me out with this ?

Comment: You might waant to add a language-tag.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Until you [edit] your question to confirm that it's assembly (and which architecture!!) (or correct that to whatever language it should be), this question stays **unclear**. After that, it will only be **too broad**. My tip: Find a good tutorial and read that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like AP stands for assembly language programming.
Assembly Language :
Assume you have the replacement string. 
Algorithm :
1. count the number of characters in the second string
2. shift all the letters in the first string starting from * by n spaces to right.
3. point si to the * character in the first string and di to the second character in the second string.
4. go on copying character by character till the end.

Java :
if you are using java. You can use the replace function in the string class or substring function to work your solution.

Answer (score 0):

AP Computer Science classes almost *always* give students a general understanding in Java. So, I'm going to assume you're using Java. So, in Java, the String class supplies you with a number of replacing methods, one of which being the replaceFirst method. Using this method in your situation would look like this:

```
Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
String manipulation = get.nextLine();
String replace = get.nextLine();
return(manipulation.replaceFirst("*",replace);
```